# How to do update doc in Elasticsearch .net client 7.4?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

As I am new with "Elasticsearch" I need your help!.
I use the version 7.4 of "Elasticsearch" and I noticed a lot of changes from other versions.
I try to update some docs added in Index, but I get error 403.
Now with this las version like is mentionned in documentation, the Type is removed.
this is my code for update:

`var index = client.Update<Person>(item.Id, u => u.Doc(item));`

in the other version we can set the type but now the type is default "_doc".

Comment: 403 is forbidden. Do you have any basic authentication set up in elastic search

Comment: Ok, for first time when create the index is work, but for update I need to authentication?

Comment: If any authentication is set on elastic search then you need to pass username and password.  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(mEsQuerySource.Url));
    settings.BasicAuthentication("user", "plain text password");
    mClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

Answer (score 0):

I use update code something like this in my project. But my elasticsearch version is
7.3

```
var responseUpdate = _elasticClient.Update<TEntity>(new DocumentPath<TEntity>(result), u =>
                                                                                 u.Doc(result).Refresh(Elasticsearch.Net.Refresh.WaitFor));
```

result variable is my entity coming form efcore.

I hope it's help to you

Answer (score 0):

After I passed a lot of search about my problem.
I found than elasticsearch block my Index to readonly for reason of space disk, is not because authentication.
For that, I changed the settings of my index like this:

```
PUT /name_index/_settings/
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

More informations:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/config-error-403-forbidden-blocked-by-forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api-cluster-block-exception-blocked-by-forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/113361/5

Thank you for help!
Have a good day :)